# Получение комментариев facebook через post запрос

Tags: python, post, requests

Пробую получить комментарии в facebook

Запрос происходит по ссылке: https://www.facebook.com/ajax/ufi/comment_fetch.php?dpr=1

Скопировал полностью Request Headers, кроме

```
:authority:www.facebook.com
:method:POST
:path:/ajax/ufi/comment_fetch.php?dpr=1
:scheme:https
```

И попробовал выполнить `post` запрос

```
r = requests.post('https://www.facebook.com/ajax/ufi/comment_fetch.php?dpr=1', headers = headers)
```

На запрос получаю ошибку 408

Comment: вам нужно залогиниться на сайте и без правильных cookies эта ссылку ведет в пустоту

Comment: посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510850/python-facebook-api-need-a-working-example